# The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a web service hosted on IIS 7 in a .net application. I just added a new Function that accepts a larger string64 formatted parameter.

When calling this function from my program I'm getting the below error. I've tried adding reader quotas to the binding, but that does not fix the problem, I still get the error.

Any and all help appreciated.

Exact Error I'm getting...

> ERRORThe formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:Payload. The InnerException message was 'There was
>   an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The maximum
>   string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML
>   data. This quota may be increased by changing the
>   MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
>   object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 10582.'. 
>   Please see InnerException for more details.

Here is my Web.config file... Notice I've increased the maxrequestlength, maxReceivedMessageSize, maxStringContentLength by a factor of 10 to 81920.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="81920"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel" />
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" maxReceivedMessageSize="81920">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="81920" maxArrayLength="6000000" maxBytesPerRead="40960" maxNameTableCharCount="163840" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ToolsSvc.IToolsService">
        <endpoint address="http://{URL}.com/ToolsSerivce/Tools.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          contract="ToolsSvc.IToolsService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you recycled your app pool, or killed your IISExpress instance to ensure config file is re-read?

Comment: I've stopped and started the webserver.